# What is the URL pattern for a 32 bit hex value?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need a URL pattern to match all hex values of 32 bit (0-9, a-f). 
I know that I can match an integer with `(?P<integer>\d+)`, what if the value is a **32 bit hex**?
Thanks

Comment: `(?P<whatever>[a-z0-9]+)` or `(?P<whatever >[:alnum:]+)`